# If $T$ is a homeomorphism and $\Omega$ is invariant under $T$, can we infer that $T(\Omega)=\Omega$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, diffeomorphism

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $T$ be a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^d$ onto $\mathbb R^d$ and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be invariant under $T$, i.e. $T(\Omega)\subseteq\Omega$.

Can we somehow infer (maybe by assuming that $T$ is even a $C^1$-diffeomorphism and/or $\Omega$ is closed/open) that $T(\Omega)=\Omega$?

Comment: Counterexample for $d=1$ let $T(x)=x+1$ and $\Omega=(0,\infty)$. More generally, if $T$ is a translation of $\mathbb R^d$ and not the identity, then there is a set $\Omega$ such that $T(\Omega)$ is a proper subset of $\Omega$.

Comment: @bof Is there a name for maps $T$ which satisfy $T(\Omega)=\Omega$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Consider $T : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by
$$T(x)=\frac{x}{2}$$

and $\Omega = B(0,1)$ (the ball centered of $0$ and of radius $1$, closed or open as you prefer).

Comment: Sure. Or you could use a translation.

Comment: Is there a name for maps $T$ which satisfy $T(\Omega)=\Omega$?

Comment: If $T$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T(\Omega)=\Omega$, then the restriction $T_{|\Omega}$ is a homeomorphism of $\Omega$.